# Can I host images in heroku? Or do I need S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm deploying my web app (it's for a corporate client). So, users will not add images, but only the business will.

I've deployed to Heroku, and my images are still showing. When do I need to use S3? Ill have like 100 images in total in the site, and size will vary like > 7 a week. Can I use only heroku?

Comment: I think heroku will allow your app  to grow (accept uploads) till the size of your heroku app reaches 500 MB (including the public directory which suppose to hold your images)... So if you think the clients will upload images that in total will be greater than 450MB will work... Greater than that I really don't know what will happen.

Comment: You don't need to use S3, you can use any of Heroku's add-ons. As for just using Heroku, if you plan on having a file upload button in your app, then every time you push to heroku your files will be wiped out, because Heroku overwrites itself with each push.

Comment: @JoeKennedy wow... Well, admin people will upload new files so I think it's not a good idea tu use Heroku then!

Comment: @Joe make a very pertinant point.  For the application I am working on (see http://quiet-fortress-3338.herokuapp.com/) I use Heroku for the static background image of a drill (top left) and Amazon S3 for images attached to articles e.g.the "wizard" on above page.  Pierre

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The short answer: if you allow users or admins to upload images, you should not use Heroku's file system for this as the images will suddenly vanish.

As explained in the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem):

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted.

This means that user uploaded images on the Heroku filesystem are not only wiped out with every push, but also with every dyno restart, which occasionally happens (even if you would ping them frequently to prevent them going to sleep).

Once you start using a second web dyno, it will not be able to read the other dyno's filesystem, so then images would only be visible from one dyno. This would cause weird issues where users can sometimes see images and sometimes they don't.

That said, you can temporarily store images on the Heroku filesystem if you implement [a pass-through file upload to an external file store](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3#pass-through-uploads).

Comment: Understood perfectly. Clear answer! Thanks

Comment: @fivedigit How does one upload to the local storage?  My use case works ideally with uploaded data being destroyed following end of session or deployment etc.  the heroku webiste talks about :local other posts reference /tmp ?  I just want to upload to herokus local storage but cannot find an example of how...

Answer (score 15):

**Asset Pipeline**

`FiveDigit`'s answer is very good - there is something more to consider; the role of the [`asset pipeline`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-the-asset-pipeline-questionmark) in Rails

If the images you have are used as *assets* (IE they are used in the layout; are not changeable by the user), then you can store them in the `assets/images` folder. There is no limit to the number of assets you can keep with your application, but you must be sure on what these are - they are files which aid your application's operation; *not* files which can be uploaded / manipulated:

> The asset pipeline provides a framework to concatenate and minify or
>   compress JavaScript and CSS assets. It also adds the ability to write
>   these assets in other languages and pre-processors such as
>   CoffeeScript, Sass and ERB.

The asset pipeline will compress & fingerprint the `stylesheet`, `image` and `js` files it has, when you deploy your application to the likes of Heroku, or any other server. This means if those files don't change, you can store them in there

-

**S3**

The reason you'd want to use the likes of `S3` is specifically if your images files are designed to change (user can upload / edit them). Regardless of Heroku's filesystem, if the images are tied to changes in the DB, you'll have to keep a central store for them - if you change servers, they need to be reachable

To do this, you should ensure you appreciate how you want the files to work - are they going to be manipulated constantly by the user or not? If so, you'll have to explore integrating `S3` into your app

Comment: Hi again Rich! Ill use S3 because although I'll have a small amount of images, they will change every day...

Comment: What about images innate to the application? For example, the logo or an image in the 'About' page. Will these be deleted by Heroku? Also, Heroku doesn't even let me upload a file - it's not that I upload it and it gets deleted (I'm using Laravel not Rails)

Comment: If it's in the asset pipeline, it's fine (these files are refreshed with each deploy) - if you're storing files from users, you will need to use something like S3

Comment: I'm not sure what the asset pipeline is (as I said I use Laravel). Laravel has a `storage/app/public/img` directory that you can symlink to `public/img`. But, regardless, how does Heroku delete the images? Images are files. Does it delete all files? What difference does it make who uploads the file? I can store any file (ex: image) I want in the same directory (ex: public/img). How would Heroku know who uploaded the file and what does it matter? So confusing!

Comment: I think I figured it out. Any changes made to the application (ex: file upload) while the dyno is running, will only exist for as long as the dyno is running. When the dyno restarts, it will re-create itself using the last deploy (which doesn't have the new changes). Is that right @RichardPeck?

Comment: The asset pipeline is basically just the raw asset files you have in your application. When you "push" the app, Heroku "builds" a compiled version of the files and puts them into the public folder. It works similarly to how webpack works for JS.

Comment: The problem with Heroku is that each time you "push" a new version of the app, all the older files are replaced with the new ones you've just pushed. This means that if you have user uploaded files (that are not present in the application's GIT repo), they'll be removed when the new deploy is put into the dyno.

Comment: https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted This explains it properly