# Carrierwave_backgrounder and delayed_job not working on Heroku: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, delayed-job

I am using the Carrierwave_backgrounder, delayed_job and daemons gem to handle uploading multiple images on my application without stealing bandwidth from other users immediately. The worker will run with no issues on my local development server. After pushing to my Heroku staging environment I receive these errors while attempting to complete the jobs.

```
  Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (2.5ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2015-10-28 23:46:15.299335', locked_by = 'host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3' WHERE id IN (SELECT  "delayed_jobs"."id" FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2015-10-28 23:46:15.298692' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2015-10-28 19:46:15.298734') OR locked_by = 'host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3') AND failed_at IS NULL)  ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
[Worker(host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3)] Job CarrierWave::Workers::StoreAsset (id=20) RUNNING
2015-10-28T23:46:15+0000: [Worker(host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3)] Job CarrierWave::Workers::StoreAsset (id=20) RUNNING
  VehicleImage Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "vehicle_images".* FROM "vehicle_images" WHERE "vehicle_images"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 91]]
[Worker(host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3)] Job CarrierWave::Workers::StoreAsset (id=20) FAILED (4 prior attempts) with Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /app/public/uploads/tmp/1446075582-3-5608/Cancer_show_031.JPG
2015-10-28T23:46:15+0000: [Worker(host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3)] Job CarrierWave::Workers::StoreAsset (id=20) FAILED (4 prior attempts) with Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /app/public/uploads/tmp/1446075582-3-5608/Cancer_show_031.JPG
   (0.6ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.8ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET "attempts" = $1, "run_at" = $2, "locked_at" = $3, "locked_by" = $4, "updated_at" = $5 WHERE "delayed_jobs"."id" = $6  [["attempts", 5], ["run_at", "2015-10-28 23:56:45.308678"], ["locked_at", nil], ["locked_by", nil], ["updated_at", "2015-10-28 23:46:15.310442"], ["id", 20]]
   (1.4ms)  COMMIT
  Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (2.0ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2015-10-28 23:46:15.318187', locked_by = 'host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3' WHERE id IN (SELECT  "delayed_jobs"."id" FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2015-10-28 23:46:15.317874' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2015-10-28 19:46:15.317891') OR locked_by = 'host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3') AND failed_at IS NULL)  ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
[Worker(host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3)] Job CarrierWave::Workers::StoreAsset (id=21) RUNNING
2015-10-28T23:46:15+0000: [Worker(host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3)] Job CarrierWave::Workers::StoreAsset (id=21) RUNNING
  VehicleImage Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "vehicle_images".* FROM "vehicle_images" WHERE "vehicle_images"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 92]]
[Worker(host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3)] Job CarrierWave::Workers::StoreAsset (id=21) FAILED (4 prior attempts) with Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /app/public/uploads/tmp/1446075582-3-0693/Cancer_show_033.JPG
2015-10-28T23:46:15+0000: [Worker(host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3)] Job CarrierWave::Workers::StoreAsset (id=21) FAILED (4 prior attempts) with Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /app/public/uploads/tmp/1446075582-3-0693/Cancer_show_033.JPG
   (0.6ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.2ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET "attempts" = $1, "run_at" = $2, "locked_at" = $3, "locked_by" = $4, "updated_at" = $5 WHERE "delayed_jobs"."id" = $6  [["attempts", 5], ["run_at", "2015-10-28 23:56:45.322803"], ["locked_at", nil], ["locked_by", nil], ["updated_at", "2015-10-28 23:46:15.324371"], ["id", 21]]
   (1.5ms)  COMMIT
  Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (2.2ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2015-10-28 23:46:15.329835', locked_by = 'host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3' WHERE id IN (SELECT  "delayed_jobs"."id" FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2015-10-28 23:46:15.329385' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2015-10-28 19:46:15.329409') OR locked_by = 'host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3') AND failed_at IS NULL)  ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
[Worker(host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3)] Job CarrierWave::Workers::StoreAsset (id=22) RUNNING
2015-10-28T23:46:15+0000: [Worker(host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3)] Job CarrierWave::Workers::StoreAsset (id=22) RUNNING
  VehicleImage Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "vehicle_images".* FROM "vehicle_images" WHERE "vehicle_images"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 93]]
[Worker(host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3)] Job CarrierWave::Workers::StoreAsset (id=22) FAILED (4 prior attempts) with Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /app/public/uploads/tmp/1446075582-3-8474/Cancer_show_034.JPG
2015-10-28T23:46:15+0000: [Worker(host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3)] Job CarrierWave::Workers::StoreAsset (id=22) FAILED (4 prior attempts) with Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /app/public/uploads/tmp/1446075582-3-8474/Cancer_show_034.JPG
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.9ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET "attempts" = $1, "run_at" = $2, "locked_at" = $3, "locked_by" = $4, "updated_at" = $5 WHERE "delayed_jobs"."id" = $6  [["attempts", 5], ["run_at", "2015-10-28 23:56:45.336065"], ["locked_at", nil], ["locked_by", nil], ["updated_at", "2015-10-28 23:46:15.338022"], ["id", 22]]
   (1.7ms)  COMMIT
  Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (1.9ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2015-10-28 23:46:15.344057', locked_by = 'host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3' WHERE id IN (SELECT  "delayed_jobs"."id" FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2015-10-28 23:46:15.343691' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2015-10-28 19:46:15.343713') OR locked_by = 'host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3') AND failed_at IS NULL)  ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
[Worker(host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3)] 3 jobs processed at 62.5742 j/s, 3 failed
2015-10-28T23:46:15+0000: [Worker(host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3)] 3 jobs processed at 62.5742 j/s, 3 failed
  Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (1.4ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2015-10-28 23:46:15.347046', locked_by = 'host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3' WHERE id IN (SELECT  "delayed_jobs"."id" FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2015-10-28 23:46:15.346718' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2015-10-28 19:46:15.346737') OR locked_by = 'host:7db12935-5a60-41b4-892b-934f088b53d5 pid:3') AND failed_at IS NULL)  ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
```

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

**uploaders/image_uploader.rb**

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include ::CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay
```

**config/initializers/carrierwave_backgrounder.rb**

```
CarrierWave::Backgrounder.configure do |c|
  c.backend :delayed_job, queue: :carrierwave
  # c.backend :resque, queue: :carrierwave
  # c.backend :sidekiq, queue: :carrierwave
  # c.backend :girl_friday, queue: :carrierwave
  # c.backend :sucker_punch, queue: :carrierwave
  # c.backend :qu, queue: :carrierwave
  # c.backend :qc
end
```

**vehicle_image.rb**

```
class VehicleImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vehicle
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  process_in_background :image
  store_in_background :image

  def set_to_primary_and_save
    VehicleImage.where(vehicle: vehicle).update_all(primary: false)
    self.primary = true
    save
  end

end
```

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Seems like heroku only uses images in the asset pipeline. You may need an external service for image uploads such as s3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yah, basically you should upload images to other services such as AWS S3. Because the Heroku doesn't allow we upload images. You can read more at here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24646941/5126985