# Angular - Avoid to recompile on file upload in assets folder

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on an application that allow the user to upload images on the assets folder:

```
assets\ProductImage
```

Each time I test the application and I upload an image the node server recompiles the app and reloads the browser.

Is there a way to avoid this?

I mean: I want to recompile the app if I change a .ts or .html files but not if I upload images in the `assets\ProductImage` folder.

Thanks to support

Comment: You should keep the target upload folder outside of your web servers root folder. It is bad practice to upload in your assets folder.

Comment: Can you give the details of the build configuration done for the build tool you are using. Like webpack configuration or something ?

Comment: I'm using VS Code with node js, I don't know what you mean Luke... Do you need to see some specific file?

Comment: @trichetriche Yes I know but this was my first Angular application and someone more expert then me suggested to put all on assets folder... What can be a good folder to place the files ?

Comment: Well then, you're the expert @DarioN1 ! Be sure to tell him that ;) you should use a dedicated folder on your server, it can be everywhere you want, but not in your web folder.

Comment: Thanks @trichetriche , I  don't remember wht we use assets folder... It was due to some problems between development environment and production enviromnent...

Comment: Then you should resolve the environment issue. Pushing to the assets folder will result in loss of files when you deploy your application. For instance, see this **[verified answer about Heroku, a hosting service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642967/can-i-host-images-in-heroku-or-do-i-need-s3)**