# multer not storing image to folder

Tags: node.js, image, express, heroku, multer

I deployed my express app on heroku and am attempting to upload images using multer. This all works perfectly on localhost but on heroku when I upload an image it will not save to my images folder, and I get a 500 server error with:
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../images/kauai-mountain.jpg'

I am using create react app on front end.

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => { 
        cb(error, '../images/');
     },
     filename: (req, file, cb) => {
         cb(null, file.originalname);
     }
});

router.post('/', multer({ storage }).single('image'), (req, res) => {
    const { description, category } = req.body;
    const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host');

    const newPost = new Post({
        description,
        category,
        imagePath: url + '/images/' + req.file.filename
    });

    newPost.save().then(post => res.json(post)).catch(e => res.json(e));
});
```

server.js

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
    app.use('/', express.static('client/build'));

    app.get('*' , (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}
```

My front end code is uploading the image and sending it to the route, the error is in the back end.

**EDIT**
I am reading that the problem may be that heroku cant save images consistently. I don't understand because I am saving them in an images folder on my server which I run on heroku. Could this be the problem?

Comment: May be a silly question, but is the second .jpg in the filename '../images/kauai-mountain.jpg.jpg' expected? Can you print req.file.filename to the console and share the result?

Comment: I fixed that typo. The filename should be good, works perfect on local host but when I pushed to heroku I get  a 500 code with every post to server..

Comment: I see. If your images folder is empty at the beginning, maybe the following could be helpful: https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/591

Comment: The folder exists a put a sample image in it so I could upload it to github since heroku uses the git repository

Comment: This question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642967/can-i-host-images-in-heroku-or-do-i-need-s3)